# How to create specific file format with core Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to create specific file format for example `.mxd` (ArcGIS Map Document format) using core python? For example I am trying to create `.mxd` files form the array of `counties`

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/Test"
counties = ['Benton', 'Caroll','Polk','Scot']
for mxd in counties:
   f = open(mxd+".mxd")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes", you could conceivably create any old format in Python (and there are libraries for many widely used formats, e.g. [`arcpy`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-arcpy-.htm) for ArcPy map documents).

But just naming the file with a `.mxd` extension doesn't make it a ArcGIS Map Document; if the *contents* don't match the required format, anything that expects that format will fail when it tries to use it. It's usually pretty involved to match custom file formats, so when a package can handle the serialization and parsing for you, *use it*. Plain old `open` won't do *anything* special based on the file name extension, but you might need to use it to open the raw file (usually in binary mode) then pass the resulting file handle to the library's parsing or serialization API. Read the `arcpy` docs for what it expects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I couldn't find any thing in ArcPy to create the MXDs in Stand alone file

Comment: @MonaCoder: Very first hit when I searched `arcpy mxd` was to [this page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm), which includes [code samples illustrating basic usage at the bottom](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm#C_GUID-CCD917AA-83A1-497A-AE17-2665B62CAC34).